# Removing .mouseenter when viewing on narrow displays

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to Jquery and JS, so hope someone will be able to help! I've built my first image slider and it is all functioning well, except o handheld devices. Basically, when the width drops below a certain point, the slides overlay, but when I hove over, rather than being able to click the link on the slide, the last slide is displayed.

I'm pretty sure the easiest fix would be to remove the .mouseenter function on small screens. I have tried:

```
$(function(){
var mobile;
if (window.width < 481) {
mobile = 1;
}
if (!mobile) {
```

But this doesn't seem to do anything. Any advice or help as to how I can fix this would be much appreciated

Full slidenav.js

```
    // Run the following code once the window has loaded all elements

$(window).load(function(){

    // Set variables to hide background divs and set opacity of foreground divs to 0 (these won't run yet)

    var hideSlide1 = function(){ $('#slidenavimg1').animate({'opacity':'0'},500); $('.button-one').animate({'opacity':'0'},300); };
    var hideSlide2 = function(){ $('#slidenavimg2').animate({'opacity':'0'},500); $('.button-two').animate({'opacity':'0'},300); };
    var hideSlide3 = function(){ $('#slidenavimg3').animate({'opacity':'0'},500); $('.button-three').animate({'opacity':'0'},300); };
    var hideSlide4 = function(){ $('#slidenavimg4').animate({'opacity':'0'},500); $('.button-four').animate({'opacity':'0'},300); };
    var hideSlide5 = function(){ $('#slidenavimg5').animate({'opacity':'0'},500); $('.button-five').animate({'opacity':'0'},300); };

    // Set variables to show background divs and set opacity of foreground divs to 1 (these won't run yet)

    var showSlide1 = function(){ $('#slidenavimg1').animate({'opacity':'1'},500); $('.button-one').animate({'opacity':'1'},300); };
    var showSlide2 = function(){ $('#slidenavimg2').animate({'opacity':'1'},500); $('.button-two').animate({'opacity':'1'},300); };
    var showSlide3 = function(){ $('#slidenavimg3').animate({'opacity':'1'},500); $('.button-three').animate({'opacity':'1'},300); };
    var showSlide4 = function(){ $('#slidenavimg4').animate({'opacity':'1'},500); $('.button-four').animate({'opacity':'1'},300); };
    var showSlide5 = function(){ $('#slidenavimg5').animate({'opacity':'1'},500); $('.button-five').animate({'opacity':'1'},300); };

    // Run the functions to hide 2nd and 3rd divs

    hideSlide2();
    hideSlide3();
    hideSlide4();
    hideSlide5();

    var blockOne = function(){
            showSlide1();
            hideSlide2();
            hideSlide3();
            hideSlide4();
            hideSlide5();
    };

    var blockTwo = function(){
            showSlide2();
            hideSlide1();
            hideSlide3();
            hideSlide4();
            hideSlide5();
    };

    var blockThree = function(){
            showSlide3();
            hideSlide1();
            hideSlide2();
            hideSlide4();
            hideSlide5();

    };

    var blockFour = function(){
            showSlide4();
            hideSlide1();
            hideSlide2();
            hideSlide3();
            hideSlide5();

    };

    var blockFive = function(){
            showSlide5();
            hideSlide1();
            hideSlide2();
            hideSlide3();
            hideSlide4();

    };

    var hcD1;
    var hcD2;
    var hcD3;
    var hcD4;
    var hcV1;
    var hcV2;
    var hcV3;
    var hcV4;
    var hcH1;
    var hcH2;
    var hcH3;
    var hcH4;
    var hcM1;
    var hcM2;
    var hcM3;
    var hcM4;
    var hcB1;
    var hcC1;
    var hcD1;
    var hcE1;


    function hcIconLoop(){

                blockOne();
                hcT1= window.setTimeout(function() {
                    blockTwo();
                }, 5000);
                hcT2= window.setTimeout(function() {
                        blockThree();
                }, 10000);
                hcT3= window.setTimeout(function() {
                        blockFour();
                }, 15000);
                hcT4= window.setTimeout(function() {
                        blockFive();
                }, 20000);


        };

    function hcIconLoopB(){

                blockTwo();
                hcD1= window.setTimeout(function() {
                    blockThree();
                }, 5000);
                hcD2= window.setTimeout(function() {
                        blockFour();
                }, 10000);

                hcD3= window.setTimeout(function() {
                        blockFive();
                }, 15000);

                hcD4= window.setTimeout(function() {
                        blockOne();
                }, 20000);

        };

    function hcIconLoopC(){

                blockThree();
                hcV1= window.setTimeout(function() {
                    blockFour();
                }, 5000);
                hcV2= window.setTimeout(function() {
                        blockFive();
                }, 10000);
                hcV3= window.setTimeout(function() {
                        blockOne();
                }, 15000);
                hcV4= window.setTimeout(function() {
                        blockTwo();
                }, 20000);

        };


            function hcIconLoopD(){

                blockFour();
                hcH1= window.setTimeout(function() {
                    blockFive();
                }, 5000);
                hcH2= window.setTimeout(function() {
                        blockOne();
                }, 10000);
                hcH3= window.setTimeout(function() {
                        blockTwo();
                }, 15000);
                hcH4= window.setTimeout(function() {
                        blockThree();
                }, 20000);

        };


            function hcIconLoopE(){

                blockFive();
                hcM1= window.setTimeout(function() {
                    blockOne();
                }, 5000);
                hcM2= window.setTimeout(function() {
                        blockTwo();
                }, 10000);
                hcM3= window.setTimeout(function() {
                        blockThree();
                }, 15000);
                hcM4= window.setTimeout(function() {
                        blockFour();
                }, 20000);

        };





        hcIconLoop();

        hcI1= window.setInterval(hcIconLoop, 25000);

        function hcEndLoop(){
            window.clearTimeout(hcT1);
            window.clearTimeout(hcT2);
            window.clearTimeout(hcT3);
            window.clearTimeout(hcT4);
            window.clearInterval(hcI1);
        }

        function hcEndLoop2() {
            window.clearTimeout(hcD1);
            window.clearTimeout(hcD2);
            window.clearTimeout(hcD3);
            window.clearTimeout(hcD4);
            window.clearInterval(hcB1);
        }

        function hcEndLoop3() {
            window.clearTimeout(hcV1);
            window.clearTimeout(hcV2);
            window.clearTimeout(hcV3);
            window.clearTimeout(hcV4);
            window.clearInterval(hcC1);
        }

        function hcEndLoop4() {
            window.clearTimeout(hcH1);
            window.clearTimeout(hcH2);
            window.clearTimeout(hcH3);
            window.clearTimeout(hcH4);
            window.clearInterval(hcD1);
        }

        function hcEndLoop5() {
            window.clearTimeout(hcM1);
            window.clearTimeout(hcM2);
            window.clearTimeout(hcM3);
            window.clearTimeout(hcM4);
            window.clearInterval(hcE1);
        }

    $(function(){
var mobile;
if (window.width < 481) {
mobile = 1;
}
if (!mobile) {  




        $('.button-one').mouseenter(function(){
            $('.imgcont li').stop();
            $('.cta li').stop();
        blockOne();
        hcEndLoop();
        hcEndLoop2();
        hcEndLoop3();
        hcEndLoop4();
        hcEndLoop5();

    });

    $('.button-two').mouseenter(function(){
        $('.imgcont li').stop();
            $('.cta li').stop();
        blockTwo();
        hcEndLoop();
        hcEndLoop2();
        hcEndLoop3();
        hcEndLoop4();
        hcEndLoop5();
    });

    $('.button-three').mouseenter(function(){
        $('.imgcont li').stop();
            $('.cta li').stop();
        blockThree();
        hcEndLoop();
        hcEndLoop2();
        hcEndLoop3();
        hcEndLoop4();
        hcEndLoop5();
    });

    $('.button-four').mouseenter(function(){
        $('.imgcont li').stop();
            $('.cta li').stop();
        blockFour();
        hcEndLoop();
        hcEndLoop2();
        hcEndLoop3();
        hcEndLoop4();
        hcEndLoop5();
    });

    $('.button-five').mouseenter(function(){
        $('.imgcont li').stop();
            $('.cta li').stop();
        blockFive();
        hcEndLoop();
        hcEndLoop2();
        hcEndLoop3();
        hcEndLoop4();
        hcEndLoop5();
    });

    $('.cta').mouseleave(function(){

    if ($('.button-one').css('opacity') == 1) {
            hcIconLoop();
            hcI1= window.setInterval(hcIconLoop, 25000);
    }

    else if ($('.button-two').css('opacity') == 1) {
            hcIconLoopB();
            hcB1= window.setInterval(hcIconLoopB, 25000);
    }

    else if ($('.button-three').css('opacity') == 1) {
            hcIconLoopC();
            hcC1= window.setInterval(hcIconLoopC, 25000);
    }

    else if ($('.button-four').css('opacity') == 1) {
            hcIconLoopD();
            hcD1= window.setInterval(hcIconLoopD, 25000);
    }

    else if ($('.button-five').css('opacity') == 1) {
            hcIconLoopE();
            hcE1= window.setInterval(hcIconLoopE, 25000);
    }

    });




}
});





});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as `window.width`.

Instead, you have to use `window.innerWidth`. And if you use jQuery, you can use `$(window).width()`.